# Transition using integral of partial derivatives unclear

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I hope I am not overreaching my boundaries on this one, but I have been trying to wrap my head around a claim I read in a paper and would greatly appreciate any help on figuring it out. In the following paper: [Axiomatic Attribution for Deep Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01365.pdf) the authors stated the following:

$ IG_i::= (x_i-x'_i)\int^1_0\frac{dF(x'+\alpha(x-x'))}{dx_i}d\alpha $

And then:

$\sum^n_{i=1}IG_i(x)=F(x)-F(x')$

I can't seem to prove this transition (from the first to the second) and there is no proof supplied in the paper (which makes me think that there's something trivial I am missing...).

Would be grateful for any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Define $g(\alpha) = F(x'+\alpha(x-x'))$. Use the chain rule to find $g'(\alpha)$. Note that $\int_0^1 g'=g(1)-g(0)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Indeed, I agree - I was thinking along a different line. Thanks! :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I still have two issues though: (1) We're deriving $F$ by $x_i$ inside the integral (not by what we would have expected from the chain rule (the term inside $F$); (2)  We're still summing over all $i=1,...,n$ in the final term to reach $F(x)-F(x')$ - so how can we explain that?

Comment: What _does_ the chain rule say $g'(\alpha)$ is? This is the several-variables chain rule we're talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completion, here are the full steps (thanks to David Ullrich):

Define:

$g(\alpha) = F(x'+\alpha(x-x'))$

$y=x'+\alpha(x-x')$

Where $F(\cdot)$ is a scalar and $x$ and $x'$ are vectors (and therefore $y$ is too).

Then:
$g'(\alpha) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} = (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_1}(x_1-x'_{1}), \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_2}(x_2-x'_{2}), ..., \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_n}(x_n-x'_{n}) )= \sum_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_i}(x_i - x'_{i})$

Notice that the second step follows because we're deriving a scalar by a vector (i.e. $F(\cdot)$ by $y$).

Now integrate over $\alpha$:

$\int_{\alpha =0}^{1} g'(\alpha)d\alpha = \int_{\alpha =0}^{1} \sum_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_i}(x_i - x'_{i}) = \sum_i \int_{\alpha =0}^{1} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_i}(x_i - x'_{i}) = \sum_i IG_i$

Notice that:

$\int_{\alpha =0}^{1} g'(\alpha)d\alpha = F(x)-F(x')$

Q.E.D :)